# Prevent flutter text form field validation message ellipsis

Tags: flutter

In flutter form validation, if error message overflow the screen size it will ellipsis, however, I want to display error message completely and if the message overflows the screen size it will continue to the next line.
here is example code is written in flutter official doc:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can read more about flutter form validation here: [Build a form with validation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can add decoration as InputDecoration and Set errorMaxLines Size. Like code as Below

```
 TextFormField(
           decoration: const InputDecoration(
           errorMaxLines: 2),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Multiline error text will effect all ui arragement.