# Control Text Overflow of Floating Label of readonly TextFormField on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm having a readonly `TextFormField` [widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) like this:

```
TextFormField(
      /// field must neither be focusable, nor must value be editable by input
      canRequestFocus: false,
      readOnly: true,

      controller: _textEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontSize: 20,
        letterSpacing: 1,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
      ),
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 1,
      validator: null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 15.0,
          horizontal: 15.0,
        ),
        errorStyle: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 20,
          letterSpacing: 1,
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        errorMaxLines: 3,
        labelText: 'test dskjhfkjshf kdjdfhkjshf ksdjfhkjshf ksjdhfkjshdf kjhfkjshkf skjdfhkjsdjhf kjdhfkhsf',
        labelStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) =>
                  TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                  ),
        ),
        floatingLabelStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            return TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: 20,
              letterSpacing: 1,
              fontFamily: 'Arial',
            );
          },
        ),
        counterText: '',
      ),
    )
```

I've tried to set the `overflow: TextOverflow.visible` of the `floatingLabelStyle` and the `labelStyle` properties, but this does not do anything, the example keeps overflowing in an ellipsis.

There is exactly [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836750/prevent-flutter-text-form-field-validation-message-ellipsis) discussed with regards to the error message overflowing, where the only way is to set the `errorMaxLines` of the `InputDecoration` to an integer bigger than 1. But there is no `floatingLabelMaxLines` or such, so I'm wondering if it's even possible?

I'm trying this on the iPhone 15 Simulator on a MacBook Pro, iOS 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** use `InputDecoration.label` and pass a `Text` yourself instead of using `InputDecoration.labelText` that accepts a string that's getting ellipsized.

---

Let's take a look at the `TextFormField` widget source code:

```dart
           return UnmanagedRestorationScope(
             bucket: field.bucket,
             child: TextField(
               restorationId: restorationId,
               controller: state._effectiveController,
               focusNode: focusNode,
               decoration: effectiveDecoration.copyWith(errorText: field.errorText),
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/78666c8dc57e9f7548ca9f8dd0740fbf0c658dc9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart#L200C31-L200C31

It uses `TextField` widget. Okay. Let's take a look inside it then:

```dart
    if (widget.decoration != null) {
      child = AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: Listenable.merge(<Listenable>[ focusNode, controller ]),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          return InputDecorator(
            decoration: _getEffectiveDecoration(),
            baseStyle: widget.style,
            textAlign: widget.textAlign,
            textAlignVertical: widget.textAlignVertical,
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/78666c8dc57e9f7548ca9f8dd0740fbf0c658dc9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart#L1448C33-L1448C33

It uses `InputDecorator` for displaying the decoration (which holds your label). Let's look at that one then:

```dart
    final Widget? label = decoration.labelText == null && decoration.label == null ? null : _Shaker(
      animation: _shakingLabelController.view,
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        duration: _kTransitionDuration,
        curve: _kTransitionCurve,
        opacity: _shouldShowLabel ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
          duration:_kTransitionDuration,
          curve: _kTransitionCurve,
          style: widget._labelShouldWithdraw
            ? _getFloatingLabelStyle(themeData, defaults)
            : labelStyle,
          child: decoration.label ?? Text(
            decoration.labelText!,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            textAlign: textAlign,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4bc7a44eb69056a6744f576c2cea656d65b656e2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L2245-L2249

Yes. If the `InputDecoration.label` was null then it indeed passes your `labelText` to a `Text` widget that has an `overflow` explicitly set to `ellipsis`. But what if we'd put the `label` property instead then?

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: Text(lipsum),
  ),
)
```

We get a multiline label! :)

[image]

A small lesson from this comes up: dig into Flutter's source code! It's really a source of knowledge, insider info and a way to get even more insight into how Flutter works and does things, and - in case of this problem - how to solve something.

Comment: Thank you sir, perfectly understandable now and I‘ll keep that in mind before posting future questions! Absolutely helpful mate, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`labelText` is a string property that will use default styling from the framework. If a more elaborate label is required, consider using [label] instead. Which is a `Widget` property

```
TextFormField(
  controller: txtCtrl,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: const Text(
      'test dskjhfkjshf kdjdfhkjshf ksdjfhkjshf ksjdhfkjshdf kjhfkjshkf skjdfhkjsdjhf kjdhfkhsf',
    ),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
    floatingLabelStyle: MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        return const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 20,
          letterSpacing: 1,
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

result:

[image: example multi line label]

Since its `Text` widget, you can customize any styling on it.

Comment: Thanks mate! Gave the other one the „acceptance“ due to the provided elaboration details, but thanks a lot to you too!